# Dijit Tooltip that works on all html tags

Tags: tooltip, dojo

So I'm trying to use dijit tooltip. 
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Tooltip

However, they only have the attribute of "connectIds" this seems rather limiting and I'm surprised that it was programmed this way. I don't know how many hyperlinks my pages will have, so wouldn't it be better to have an option like "connectByHTMLtag" so that I can map all "a" tags to a specific tooltip? Or even a "connectClasses" would make a bit more sense.

This means I have to manually enter id="tooltip1" id="tooltip2" etc.

Anyone find a way around this??

Comment: What is it you'd like to accomplish that you find this limiting / want a way around?  Might help people suggest a particularly fitting solution.  FWIW, connectId actually accepts an array and can be fed either ids or DOM nodes (it uses byId to resolve ids to nodes anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect them when the page loads using dojo.query.

Give all of your hyperlinks a class that you can use to select them later:

```
<a href="whatever.html" class="link-tooltip">Etc</a>
```

Then in your JavaScript you can use something like this:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.query(".link-tooltip").forEach(function(node, index, arr) {

            new dijit.Tooltip({
                connectId: [node.id],
                label: "My tooltip!"
            });
        });
});
```

This code is untested, but that's basically how you could do it. dojo.query is very handy for this sort of thing!

Answer (score 0):

As of Dojo Toolkit 1.8, it is now possible to attach a tooltip via a selector:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/Tooltip", "dojo/query!css2"], function(ready, Tooltip){
    ready(function(){
        new Tooltip({
            connectId: "myTable",
            selector: "tr",
            getContent: function(matchedNode){
                return matchedNode.getAttribute("tooltipText");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Tooltip.html#attaching-to-multiple-nodes